# Routers and services invisible in Traefik dashboard (without docker)

Tags: reverse-proxy, traefik

I'm trying to run Traefik as a reverse proxy for some apps in localhost.

In the configuration file, I configured 3 routers and 2 services.
The goal is to proxify two applications I have on localhost 8080 and localhost 3000
(dev.test.fr is equivalent to localhost)

The configuration :

```
api:
  dashboard: true
  insecure: true
entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ':80'
  traefik:
    address: ':8081'
http:
  routers:
    myapi:
      rule: Host(`dev.test.fr`) && PathPrefix(`/api`)
      service: service-api
    traefik:
      rule: Host(`dev.test.com`)
      service: api@internal
    myfront:
      rule: Host(`dev.test.fr`)
      service: service-front
  services:
    service-api:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: 'http://localhost:8080/'
    service-front:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: 'http://localhost:3000/'
log:
  level: DEBUG
accessLog: {}
```

However if I go on the traefik dashboard, I don't see any of my router or service (except the internal api of traefik)

[image: traefik dashboard]

I'm not an expert on traefik so I probably miss something obvious in this configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer to my own question.
Indeed, my config file was incorrect.
It is important to have two files (and not one)

The first one is the configuration of Traefik itself

```
api:
  dashboard: true
  insecure: true
entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ':80'
  traefik:
    address: ':8081'

providers:
  file:
    directory: "traefik"

log:
  level: DEBUG
accessLog: {}
```

In this file, it's possible to configure the provider, even if it's a plain text file. It's not possible to have the configuration of the router in the same file.
The provider here is :

```
providers:
  file:
    directory: "traefik"
```

And in this directory, I have another configuration file with the definition of routers and services :

```
http:
  routers:
    myapi:
      rule: Host(`dev.malt.fr`) && PathPrefix(`/api`)
      service: service-api
      entryPoints:
        - http
    myfront:
      rule: Host(`dev.malt.fr`)
      service: service-front
      entryPoints:
        - http
  services:
    service-api:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: 'http://localhost:8080/'
    service-front:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: 'http://localhost:3000/'
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you started your traefik intance ? have you set the `--configfile config.yaml` option ?

Do you have any config parsing error in the logs ?
maybe you should add `entryPoints` option to your routers config :

```
http:
  routers:
    myapi:
      rule: Host(`dev.test.fr`) && PathPrefix(`/api`)
      service: service-api
      entryPoints: ["http"]
```

Comment: Please be careful when asking questions in an answer. Answers are intended to be self-contained and not necessitate further discussion. If you have clarifying questions, those should be posted as comments, once you have enough reputation. That said, this does at least get to a proposed answer in the end, so it's not entirely inappropriate as an answer—just a bit confusing in the delivery.